# Plotly: How to change table font size using fig.update?

Tags: python, plotly, joblib

I generate plotly tables with plolty. is it possible to set the font size with fig.update?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import joblib

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
#fig.update(set font_size here
fig.show()
```

the background is that I use the table in a pdf but also in a plotly dashboard. this is possible with joblib. for the pdf the font size is suitable. for the dashboard i would like to change it again after calling it. For example, for charts I can still change the legend with fig.update_layout(legend=dict( font=dict(size=5)). does this also work with a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run:

```
fig.update_traces(cells_font=dict(size = 15))
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Instead of the default:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
# import joblib

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
#fig.update(set font_size here
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
fig.update_traces(cells_font=dict(size = 15))
fig.show()
```

Comment: thank you. you helped for the umpteenth time

Comment: is it possible to ad a scrollbar? to remember I use the table-fig with joblib in a plotly dash board. i can open a new question if you like. Thanks

Comment: @Alex Yes, please open a new question. I'll make sure to take a look!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117581/plotly-show-table-as-fig-in-dash-and-add-scrollbar