# Show table as fig in dash and add scrollbar

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

i create tables with plotly and i show them in plotly dash. i would like to add an scroll-bar. is this possible? thanks for help

```
#generate fig

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores']),
                 cells=dict(values=[[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]))
                     ])
fig.show()
```

```
#show in dash

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
])

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

the background is that I use the table in a pdf but also in a plotly dashboard. this is possible with joblib.

Answer (score 1):

why are you showing the table as a graph object in dash
you can create a table object using the following logic from dataframe

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame([[100, 90, 80, 90], [95, 85, 75, 95]]).T
df.columns = ['A Scores', 'B Scores']
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table_id',
        columns = [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data = df.to_dict("rows"),
        row_selectable="single",
        fixed_rows={'headers': True, 'data': 0},
        fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 0},
    )
])
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

then if needed scrollbar will be added automatically (or you can change the size of the table
see https://dash.plotly.com/datatable for more info

to add scrollbar to graph object use the following

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig,style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'maxHeight': '200px'} )
])
app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: you don't have to use data frame I just adapted a existing code for you that use df

Comment: because i already created the table, save it and call it with joblib. the code, to create the table is not in the code for the app

Comment: you can try to add style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'height': 200} to your graph
this will add scroll to the all graph you may need to change the style to get an ok affect

Comment: sorry i didn´t see that your last solution only adds a scroll bar into the div. i have to check it again